# How to get the co-ordinate of a cell in gspread by using cell value in Python 3.6

Tags: python, gspread, google-sheets-query

All I have the value of a cell and I want to know the coordinates of the cell in Gspread.

Suppose I have date "12-11-2017". How can I find the coordinates of the cell that has this date? I am using python 3.6 with Gspread

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
cell = worksheet.find("12-11-2017") #Find a cell with exact string value
print("Text found at R%sC%s" % (cell.row, cell.col))
```

[Documentation](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=find) might be a good way to find what you need